# How to activate animation on Animate on Scroll library on up scroll

Tags: javascript, animation, next.js, react-animations, animate-on-scroll

I want the animation to be triggered in both down and up scroll but AOS b default on triggers animation on down scroll.

This is my code

```
 <div className={css.arrow} data-aos="fade-up">
     <Image src={img5} alt="img5" />
 </div>
```

I tried putting data-aos-mirror="true" as per this stackoverflow [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604911/how-to-trigger-animation-on-scroll-up-with-aos) but it did not work.

```
<div className={css.arrow} data-aos="fade-up data-aos-mirror="true">
     <Image src={img5} alt="img5" />
 </div>
```

Also did this but its not working

```
useEffect(()=>{
AOS.init({
  debounceDelay: 50, // the delay on debounce used while resizing window (advanced)
  once: false, // whether animation should happen only once - while scrolling down
  mirror: true, // whether elements should animate out while scrolling past them

});
}
,[])
```

Comment: In your second code block you're missing a closing quote on `data-aos="fade-up`, it should be `<div className={css.arrow} data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-mirror="true">`. Was that a typo?